# Как сделать booking на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Посоветуйте пожалуйста плагин, который включает в себя бронирование чего либо(номера в отеле). Бронирование должно происходить с проверкой свободных мест и с сохранением брони где-то в базе данных. В идеале нужно какое-то дополнение к wpbakery(visual composer pagebuilder). Есть ли такое дополнение(в том числе и платное)?

Comment: Здесь не смотрели [Плагины](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/booking/)

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но все же желательно какое-нибудь дополнение к WPbakery

Comment: @Александр так не бывает. Слишком много условий. Да вам и не нужно бронирование как дополнение. Оформление поправить не проблема. Разместить вывод плагина бронирования в сетке WPB тоже не проблема, там наверняка предусмотрены шорткоды. Поместите шорткод в текстовый блок WPB - и всё.

Comment: Хорошо, огромное спасибо, тогда воспользуюсь обычным плагином WP